# Sort lines with "natural order" in Notepad++ like Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, notepad++, sorting, text-formatting

Q: Is it possible to sort line with "natural order" (or what it calls, I'm not sure the correct name) like/similar to Windows Explorer? With or without plugin are fine

Demo lines:

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
text 03
text 04
text 100
text 101
text 202
text a100
1
```

Windows Explorer:

```
1
text 1
text 2
text 03
text 3
text 04
text 100
text 101
text 202
text a100
```

NPP with "sort by Lex. order":

```
1
text 03
text 04
text 1
text 100
text 101
text 2
text 202
text 3
text a100
```

[image: demo]

Expected behavior:

```
// just like Windows Explorer or:
1
text 03
text 04
text 1
text 2
text 3
text 100
text 101
text 202
text a100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives you the expected result:

Menu Edit >> Line Operations >> Sort Lines As Integers Ascending

**ScreenShot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried it on old version before but it didn't work, never expected that it works now